# Need some cool ideas for company's portal page

Tags: branding

Are there any list of sites that can give me an idea what all I should put on the company portal page? Manager asked me to look into re-designing the company intranet sites. I thought of news rotator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is my favorite for cultivating ideas, http://www.wssdemo.com/livepivot/ as it is specifically SharePoint targetted.

Comment: +1 it's Amazing!

Answer (score 3):

There is an annual report by the Nielsen Norman Group detailing the best Intranet designs from a pool of nominated designs. It does cost $248. I have used this report in the past and personally found it worth the money.

http://www.nngroup.com/reports/intranet/design/

If you don't want to buy the report it lists the Best Practices that it covers and you can google these to get more detailed information.

**Best Practices**

- Expertise finders (locating coworkers with specific knowledge)
- Staff directory and employee profile pages
- Knowledge management
- Company and industry news
- Editorial control of the intranet homepage and other sections
- Keeping the intranet up-to-date
- Curating content across the intranet
- User/Employee-contributed content
- Commenting features
- Ratings and feedback systems
- Increasing the level of employee participation: reward features
- CEO blogging and video
- Employee and department team sites
- Consistent navigation and clear IA
- Search
- Page templates and consistent page layout
- Video on intranets
- Data visualization
- Mega-menus for intranet navigation
- Lightboxes
- Development process for intranet redesigns
- Web analytics for intranets
- Intranet branding
- Promoting new intranet features
- Mobile intranets (including iPhone apps for intranet access)
- Personalization and ways to ensure that all users get the most from
  it